# Eclipse - Import hover missing package name and location

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

I'm wondering if anyone has seen this before and if so, how did they fix it?

Basically, when I hover over a class or annotation, when the hover dialog appears, some import statements are missing the package name and package location as you can see in the screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo76j.png

EDIT:
Sorry, if you look at the screenshot, I'm asking why the first line just has the words "Import". I know it should be "Import 'Mock' (org.Mockito)", it I click the lightbulb icon in the line number column, it shows a slightly different dialog but with the correct wording

Comment: My guess is that the missing text is there but is merged with the black background. Try with the normal color scheme and see it is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Known bug with Eclipse incorrectly calculating the length.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393602